# how to get the handle of directx fullscreen window

Tags: c++, directx, game-engine

i'm trying to get the "handle" of the specific game window.when the Game is running on fullscreen "[GetActiveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)", "[GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" such functions  are not giving the handle.

In fullscreenmode if the game is rendered using DirectX , how to get the handle of that directx fullscreen window?

Comment: Based on your previous question I would guess you need this handle to get a DC for some reason.  It would be better to ask how to do what your end goal is rather than some intermediate step.  For instance if you're looking to save a screenshot or draw over the game then ask how to do that.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks.I need this handle to get a Device Context for saving the screenshots of that Game.